# Remove the space between checkboxes

Tags: html, css

I have a form which contains several checkboxes align vertically in a div. I want to remove the space between each checkbox. But I can't find any solutions.

```
<div style="height:100px;width:25px;float:left;">
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any solution to this problem?

Comment: This *could* be a pretty tough question to answer because of differences between web browsers - I say could because you have provided quite little information about your context, say:

 * what browser are you using?
 * what doctype declaration did you use?
 * ...is the page rendering in quirks mode?
 * are you striving for cross browser compatibility?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
  <input type="checkbox" style="margin: 0; padding 0;  height:13px"/>
```

For IE, you need to set the height to remove the space between checkboxes.

Comment: does it work on your browsers?  also, note that 13 will be better if it is 13px

Comment: Yes, it works on my browsers (IE7, FF3 and Chrome).
I know "13px" is better. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

After talking to Paul O'B, a CSS guru, this is a good solution that works in IE 6, 7, 8, FF 3, and Chrome:

```
<style type="text/css">     
    #aDiv input {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display:block;
        height:12px;
        overflow:hidden
    }
</style>

<div id="aDiv" style="width:25px">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

This is using a doctype of HTML 4.01 strict.  if you want side-by-side borders for the checkboxes, use a height of 13px.

The attribute selector won't work on IE 6 so it is taken out here.  If you need to add other input element that is not a checkbox, use class instead.

Comment: Yes, Internet Explorer doesn't work. IE's behavior is always special.

Comment: solution is changed... please see the note above.

Comment: This works for me in both IE6 and IE8, standards mode. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Probably newlines between `<input>` tags are interpreted as any other whitespaces, that's why you see spaces between them. I think CSS rules has nothing to do with it.

---

**Edit:** Further investigation leads me to conclusion that whitespaces would only affect horizontal gaps. As of vertical space I believe it is impossible to assure that checkboxes will stick together without using custom graphics — web browsers are not obligated to make them perfectly square by standards, so even if you will find a way to make their bounding boxes touch each other, effect might not be satisfactory.

To make their bounding boxes as close as possible set `line-height` attribute for `div` element. With original sprites it doesn't look like you wanted it to in any browser I have tested.

Using custom graphic of some height, and identical `line-height` should do the trick.

---

**Another edit:** Some people here proposed using fixed height of input element of `13px`. Remember! It is **wrong**. You can't rely on a fact, that some browsers have built-in checkbox sprite of that height.

Answer (score 1):

There is white-space between each checkbox.  The only way to remove it is to `float` them:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .myCheckBoxDiv > input[type="checkbox"]
    {
        float: left;
    }
    .myCheckBoxDiv:after
    {
        clear: both;
        content: "";
        display: block;
    }
</style>

<div class="myCheckBoxDiv">
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set:

```
<input type="checkbox" style="margin: 0">
```

But it will not work in IE.

I think different browsers renders the html elements differently. So, it becomes difficult to get a complete hold on the situation.

However, I found one solution but this time we need to apply some trick on the body element.

The CSS will be like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    input.mycheckbox {
        height: 13px;
        width: 13px
    }

    body {
        font-size: 40%;
    }
</style>
```

And the contents within body tag is:

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<style type="text/css">
body,html,input {padding:0;margin:0;}
</style>
<div style="height:100px;width:25px;float:left;">
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
</div>
```

Edit: It's valid css now :)